# TypoScript if condition with field crdate in current year [9.5.7]

Tags: if-statement, typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I have a HMENU with `special = directory` and I try to select only these, which the field `crdate` is in the current year.

I tried the following TypoScript but they show all subpages in the tree also if they are created in 2018.

```
lib.news.jahr = COA
lib.news.jahr{
5 = TEXT
5{
    current = 1
    setCurrent.data = date:U
    setCurrent.wrap = |
    prioriCalc = 1
    strftime = %Y
    wrap = <h3>News&nbsp;|</h3>
}

10 = HMENU
10{
    special = directory
    special.value = 87
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>

    1 = TMENU
    1{
        NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>
        NO.if{
            equals.data = date:U
            equals.strftime = %Y
            equals.prioriCalc = 1
            value.data = field:crdate
            value.data.strftime = %Y
        }
    }
}
}
```

The TypoScript must work in the newest version 9.5.7

Answer (score 0):

The menu item has no if. https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/MenuObjects/Tmenuitem/Index.html.

Use something like

```
NO.allStdWrap.if {
  value.field = crdate
  value.strftime = %Y
  equals.data = date:Y
}
```

But you have to use a wrap other than wrapItemAndSub else you get empty li tags.

Or you could use USERDEF1 instead of NO and itemArrayProcFunc with a PHP function to filter the array.